# getResource with parent directory reference

Tags: java, relative-path, getresource

I have a java app where I'm trying to load a text file that will be included in the jar.

When I do `getClass().getResource("/a/b/c/")`, it's able to create the URL for that path and I can print it out and everything looks fine.

However, if I try `getClass().getResource(/a/b/../")`, then I get a `null` URL back.

It seems to not like the `..` in the path.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I can post more code if it would be helpful.

Comment: This question answers the question I was coming to search for. I have a getResource("../icons/SomeIcon.png") returning null when loading from a jar but properly returning the resource when loading from the filesystem. It sucks that Java isn't resolving the .. in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`normalize()` methods](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#normalize%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) (there are four of them) in the `FilenameUtils` class could help you. It's in the [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

```
final String name =  "/a/b/../";
final String normalizedName = FilenameUtils.normalize(name, true); // "/a/"
getClass().getResource(normalizedName);
```

Comment: Awesome this worked.  I used the normalize(name,true) method to keep unix style slashes(/) on windows systems.  Thank You!

Comment: @Trejkaz: Thank you for the edit suggestion! Unfortunately it was rejected by others and I have to edit it manually. To compensate your lost +2 points I've checked your posts and upvoted a few of them.

Answer (score 2):

The path you specify in getResource() is not a file system path and can not be resolved canonically in the same way as paths are resolved by File object (and its ilk). Can I take it that you are trying to read a resource relative to another path?

Comment: Ya so I'm getting parts of the path from different places in the code, so I when I combine the strings they have ".."'s in them.  I'm not trying to break above the base directory I get with getResource("/").  The resource I'm trying to read is relative to another path, but still inside the jar and something that I could read if I manually removed the ".." from the path.  Maybe that's what I'll have to do.